# Styles and scripts are not rendered if source is from disk. MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with rendering webpage styles and scripts. When I reference directly to library internet source for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>\
```

Everything works perfectly fine, but when I downlad all libraries using NugetPackage manager, and calling it from disk like this:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

It works as if there was no library added. This is what is is rendered on page:

```
<link href="/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

What can I check to establish what is happening?

**SOLVED:**

My problem was solved by uinstalling all jquery libraries using NuGet Package Manager tool and install it again. I guess problem was caused by uncompatibile version of libraries that was installed.

Comment: what are you using to serve the `index.html` - are you opening the index.html where the url is `file://<filepath>/index.html`

Comment: go to  solution explorer drag and drop the js file on your view

Comment: I did it this way